# d3.csv Pie Chart Example

Tags: javascript, d3.js

From reading the documentation when I apply d3.csv to

```
age,population
<5,2704659
5-13,4499890
14-17,2159981
18-24,3853788
25-44,14106543
45-64,8819342
≥65,612463
```

I believe that I should get

```
data = 
  [
    {"age": "<5", "population": "2704659"},
    {"age": "5-13", "population": "4499890"},
    {"age": "14-17", "population": "2159981"},
    {"age": "18-24", "population": "3853788"},
    {"age": "25-44", "population": "14106543"},
    {"age": "45-64", "population": "8819342"},
    {"age": "≥65", "population": "612463"},
  ]
```

However when I replace d3.csv in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/3887235 with the code sample above, nothing appears.

The change is fairly small and seems reasonable however, I cannot figure out why this is blank.

Here is a demo of what I mean : http://jsfiddle.net/dME8a/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not load the D3 library in your Fiddle.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

See update version: http://jsfiddle.net/dME8a/2/

Comment: Ahh thank you, just caught this too was about to update my post. However, I ran into an issue with transformations. If you notice in my code : http://jsfiddle.net/tqnqz/ , the labels are stacked together. Would you happen to know how to "push them out" like in http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/bundle.html

Comment: You have to do some trigonometry, play with svg transform (translate, rotate) and adjust text-anchor. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dME8a/3/